# Repeat texture like stipple

Tags: opengl-es, textures, webgl

I'm using orthographic projection.

I have 2 triangles creating one long quad.
On this quad i put a texture that repeat him self along the the way.

The world zoom is always changing by the user - and makes the quad length be short or long accordingly. The height is being calculated in the shader so it is always the same size (in pixels).

My problem is that i want the texture to repeat according to it's real (pixel size) and the length of the quad. In other words, that the texture will be always the same size (pixels) and it will fill the quad by repeating it more or less depend on the quad length.

The rotation is important.

For Example
My texture is [image]

I've added to my vertices - texture coordinates for duplicating it 20 times now
as you see below[image]
Because it's too much zoomed out we see the texture squeezed.

Now i'm zooming in and the texture stretched. It will always be 20 times repeat.
[image]

I'm sure that i have to play in with the texture coordinates in the frag shader, but don't see the solution. or perhaps there is a better solution to my problem.

---- ADDITION ----

Solved it by:
Calculating the repeat S value in the current zoom (That i'm adding the vertices) and send the map width (in world values) as attribute. Every draw i'm sending the current map width as uniform for calculating the scale.

But i'm not happy with this solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, found a way to do it with minimum attributes and minimum code in the shader.

Do Once:

- Calculating the the repeat count for each line as my world and my screen are 1:1 - 1 in my world is 1 pixel. `LineDistance(InWorldUnits)/picWidth(inScreenUnits)`
- Saving as an attribute.

Every Draw:

- Calculating the scale - world to screen - `WorldWidth/ScreenWidth`
- Setting as uniform
- Drawing the buffer

In the frag shader

- simply multiply this scale with the repeat attribute.

Works perfectly and looks good. Resizing the window is supported as well.

Answer (score 0):

The general solution is to include a texture matrix. So your vertex shader might look something like

```
attribute vec4 a_position;
attribute vec2 a_texcoord;

varying vec2 v_texcoord;

uniform mat4 u_matrix;
uniform mat4 u_texMatrix;

void main() {
  gl_Position = u_matrix * a_position;
  v_texcoord = (u_texMatrix * v_texcoord).xy;
}
```

Now you can set up texture matrix to scale your texture coordinates however you need. If your texture coordinates go from 0 to 1 across the texture and your pattern is 16 pixels wide then if you're drawing a line 100 pixels long you'd need 100/16 as your X scale.

```
var pixelsLong = 100;
var pixelsTall = 8;
var textureWidth = 16;
var textureHeight = 16;

var xScale = pixelsLong / textureWidth;
var yScale = pixelsTall / textureHeight;

var texMatrix = [
  xScale, 0, 0, 0,
  0, yScale, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 1, 0,
  0, 0, 0, 1,
];

gl.uniformMatrix4fv(texMatrixLocation, false, texMatrix);
```

That seems like it would work. Because you're using a matrix you can also easily offset or rotate the texture. See [matrix math](http://games.greggman.com/game/webgl-2d-matrices/)

Comment: The problem is that i have many lines in different sizes and many textures in different sizes, all stuffed in one buffer and one texture atlas. So using uniform is not the best solution for me. What i've done now is adding for each vertex the the world width and with uniform the current world width, and just calculating the scale. But in my opinion there must be better way. Is there anything like telling OpenGL save texture original size or something like this ?

Comment: You can pass in the texture's size as a uniform. As for using a texture atlas you can still repeat using `fract` or `mod`. Guessing you'd add a vec4 attribute with tx,ty,tw,th where tx,ty is the texcoord of the bottom,left pixel of the image in the texture atlas and tw,th is the width, height of that image. In that case you could have your actual texcoords as unit coords and expand them in the fragment shader something like `vec2 uv = fract(v_texcoords * repeatAmount) * v_imageinfo.zw + v_imageinfo.xy` or something like that. I guess I'd actually have to implement it to see if it works.

Comment: The thing is that i don't know the `repeatAmount` in the shader because it is related to the line's length and the world's scale. Well, i guess i will stick with the "one time calculation of the repeat amount and setting as attribute combine with the world width for scaling later" solution because all the given solution involves adding more attributes, and this is what i tried to avoid.

Comment: One other idea would be to use `gl_FragCoord` and some math as your texcoord. If you just use `gl_FragCoord` and some scale you'd get repeating but it would be in screen space and not move with the line. You could some how add in the starting position and orientation of the line. I doubt that will lead to the solution you want, just throwing it out there.